# Use Json object inside a function (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, json, listview, react-native

I am new to react native, hope i can explain my self enough so you'll understand.
I am trying to create a countdown to specific item on screen.
I have a working `ListView` which creates rows of items from a local `Json` (for now).
In each row i have a button which trigger a countdown specific so each row. (`onPress= function.bind(this)`)
I know my countdown algorithm works, because i tested it before with hard-coded data.

In the `onPress` function, i'm  trying to do `dateTime = json_file.Time.split(' ')` to split between date and time but i got the error

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Maybe the function doesn't "know" my Json file?
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to log json_file.Time, maybe it's not a string. `console.log(json_file.Time)`

Comment: I tried, its undefined

Comment: It's better to provide more code, your json_file is not what you think.

Comment: If i log json_file.Time from outside of the function its shows me all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is probably an array if you are creating rows of items from it. So you would have to do `json_file[i].Time.split(' ')` where `i` is the index of the row being pressed.

Comment: how do i pass the index to the functions? i use `.bind(this)`.
in the function i used rowID as in documents of react native of ListView, but i guess i don't know how to work with that index